# Change the value of variable PHP

Tags: php, variables

I have input fields, which I process with AJAX and send it on another file.
The value of the inputs is always different.
How in the file, where I get the data from AJAX, to change the variable **id** always when I get the data from AJAX.

Example:
I get the data from AJAX in this file:

```
<?php
$id=1;
echo '<div id="$id"></div>';
?>
```

Then I display the result in the page with AJAX.

```
I want the id of the div to be always different.
```

Comment: An `id` attribute MUST start with a letter, some browsers will have problems with numeric ids.

Comment: Thank you ,too ,that is very important!
I can add letters before the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want `$id` a random number use the function `rand`[link text](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php)

```
$id=rand(0,100); // random between 0 and 100, 0 and 100 incluse
```

you can also create a random string

```
function genRandomString($length) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $string = '';
    for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
        $string .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters))];
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One can create different random number through time checking, this will create random number on the basis of time and will generate different number each microseconds.

```
//this will add a char on the beginning of the value so it do not start with numeral

$str=range(a,z);

//using date function for generating random number

$i= $str[rand(0,25)].date('Ymzhisu');
```